# Not able to open ports on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I haven't been able to open ports on an EC2 instance, not even after adding them to the Security Group and Firewall.

is there any extra configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: check the Network ACL at the subnet level.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html

Comment: Is your EC2 within a VPC? Does it have internet access (ie an internet gateway)?

Comment: Could you please share more details, what exactly that you are intending to do and what is your environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "open ports"? Make your EC2 listen on the ports? Connect to other IP?

Comment: I've created a nodejs app on the home directory of the ec2 user listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080 and I added the port to the security group and firewall. I've tried 127.0.0.1:8080 with no success.

Comment: Here's the VPC details, hopefully it'll make sense
        
Route: 100     Type: ALL Traffic      Protocol: ALL          Range: ALL       Source: 0.0.0.0/0   Allow: ALLOW